# How can window.opener works after redirects?

Tags: javascript

I have **Page A**; clicking on a link, I open a **Page B** (in the same domain) as popup.

Popup make a **redirect** (Server side) to a **Page C**, **which is in another domain**!

Than **Page C** make some operations, and when it finish, redirect back to **Page B**.

Now, from **Page B**, I do :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var parent = window.opener;
    parent.HelloWorld();
</script>
```

`HelloWorld()` is a function I have on **Page A**. And it's here where happens (for me) the magic: the function is really called.

How this is possible? At that moment I call that function the parent of **Page B** should be **Page C**.

Answer (score 3):

`window.opener` is not part of any standard, so it does whatever it wants...

But https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.opener states that is a reference to the *window that created this window*, which is in fact Page A. It is *not* the page that redirected to this page (just imagine, that would imply that all pages that have been visited in this session are still in memory *and running*!).